# Create list of bigrams with all the words in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to create bigrams between all the words in a list. I can create bigrams with words + co-currents. But I can't combine one word with all the others on the list.

Script:

```
countries = ['france', 'brazil', 'usa', 'uk', 'canada', 'mexico', 'angola']

countries_bigrams = zip(*[countries[i:] for i in range(2)])

print(list(countries_bigrams))
```

My output:

> [('france', 'brazil'), ('brazil', 'usa'), ('usa', 'uk'), ('uk', 'canada'), ('canada', 'mexico'), ('mexico', 'angola')]

Good output:

> [('france', 'brazil'), ('france', 'usa'), ('france', 'uk'), ('france', 'canada'), ('france', 'mexico'), ('france', 'angola'), ('brazil', 'france'), ('brazil', 'usa'), ('brazil', 'uk'), ('brazil', 'canada'), ('brazil', 'mexico'), ('brazil', 'angola'), ...]

Comment: So simply put you want all combinations of size 2? there are plenty of examples, you can use `itertools.combinations` or `itertools.product` (depending if you want repetitions or not)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the list with itself and remove tuples of duplicate values using a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import product

countries_bigrams = [(x, y) for x, y in product(countries, repeat=2) if x != y]

print(countries_bigrams)
```

Output:

```
[('france', 'brazil'), ('france', 'usa'), ('france', 'uk'), ('france', 'canada'), ('france', 'mexico'), ('france', 'angola'), ('brazil', 'france'), ('brazil', 'usa'), ('brazil', 'uk'), ('brazil', 'canada'), ('brazil', 'mexico'), ('brazil', 'angola'), ('usa', 'france'), ('usa', 'brazil'), ('usa', 'uk'), ('usa', 'canada'), ('usa', 'mexico'), ('usa', 'angola'), ('uk', 'france'), ('uk', 'brazil'), ('uk', 'usa'), ('uk', 'canada'), ('uk', 'mexico'), ('uk', 'angola'), ('canada', 'france'), ('canada', 'brazil'), ('canada', 'usa'), ('canada', 'uk'), ('canada', 'mexico'), ('canada', 'angola'), ('mexico', 'france'), ('mexico', 'brazil'), ('mexico', 'usa'), ('mexico', 'uk'), ('mexico', 'canada'), ('mexico', 'angola'), ('angola', 'france'), ('angola', 'brazil'), ('angola', 'usa'), ('angola', 'uk'), ('angola', 'canada'), ('angola', 'mexico')]
```

Note that this is not *getting the bigrams*, your original approach already gets you the [bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram).

Comment: You might notice that good input doesn't contain set with duplicate objects, but your solution does

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate combination of size 2. A good method is using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools
countries = ['france', 'brazil', 'usa', 'uk', 'canada', 'mexico', 'angola']
list(itertools.combinations(countries, 2))
```

that give as output:

```
[('france', 'brazil'),
 ('france', 'usa'),
 ('france', 'uk'),
 ('france', 'canada'),
 ('france', 'mexico'),
 ('france', 'angola'),
 ('brazil', 'usa'),
 ('brazil', 'uk'),
 ('brazil', 'canada'),
 ('brazil', 'mexico'),
 ('brazil', 'angola'),
 ('usa', 'uk'),
 ('usa', 'canada'),
 ('usa', 'mexico'),
 ('usa', 'angola'),
 ('uk', 'canada'),
 ('uk', 'mexico'),
 ('uk', 'angola'),
 ('canada', 'mexico'),
 ('canada', 'angola'),
 ('mexico', 'angola')]
```

I think that is one of the faster method, I compered the performance on my machine:

```
%%timeit
list(itertools.combinations(countries, 2))
```

takes around 1.28 µs

```
%%timeit
[(c1, c2) for c1 in countries for c2 in countries if c1 != c2]
```

takes around 4.81 µs

```
%%timeit
countries_bigrams = [(x, y) for x, y in product(countries, repeat=2) if x != y]
```

takes around 5.81 µs

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use list comprehension:

```
[(c1, c2) for c1 in countries for c2 in countries if c1 != c2]
```

Output:

> ```
> [('france', 'brazil'),
>  ('france', 'usa'),
>  ('france', 'uk'),
>  ('france', 'canada'),
>  ('france', 'mexico'),
>  ('france', 'angola'),
>  ('brazil', 'france'),
>  ('brazil', 'usa'),
>  ('brazil', 'uk'),
>  ('brazil', 'canada'),
>  ('brazil', 'mexico'),
>  ('brazil', 'angola'),
>  ('usa', 'france'),
>  ('usa', 'brazil'),
>  ('usa', 'uk'),
>  ('usa', 'canada'),
>  ('usa', 'mexico'),
>  ('usa', 'angola'),
>  ('uk', 'france'),
>  ('uk', 'brazil'),
>  ('uk', 'usa'),
>  ('uk', 'canada'),
>  ('uk', 'mexico'),
>  ('uk', 'angola'),
>  ('canada', 'france'),
>  ('canada', 'brazil'),
>  ('canada', 'usa'),
>  ('canada', 'uk'),
>  ('canada', 'mexico'),
>  ('canada', 'angola'),
>  ('mexico', 'france'),
>  ('mexico', 'brazil'),
>  ('mexico', 'usa'),
>  ('mexico', 'uk'),
>  ('mexico', 'canada'),
>  ('mexico', 'angola'),
>  ('angola', 'france'),
>  ('angola', 'brazil'),
>  ('angola', 'usa'),
>  ('angola', 'uk'),
>  ('angola', 'canada'),
>  ('angola', 'mexico')]
> ```